# IntelliJ IDEA 14.1 - All my live templates are wiped after 14.1 update?

Tags: intellij-idea, ide, intellij-14

I have just updated my IntelliJ **IDEA 14** to **14.1** & the settings file that I have been using for a long time **does not import my live templates** despite I import it as I did previous versions.

How can I get my live templates again? They were really very useful & a result of years.

Comment: I'd open a bug on their [bug tracker](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/)

Comment: here it is @Vic: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-138464

Comment: This bug did occur during the 14.1 EAP (Early Access Program) -- see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-135950 -- I'm surprised it resurfaced. I have not experienced it again in 14.1 final. Anyhow, the only way to get your templates back is to restore the `~/.IntelliJIdea14/config/fileTemplates` directory from a backup.

Comment: I did not install EAP but I still experienced with this bug. Have been using IntelliJ IDEA for a long time & this is the first time I have experienced a issue like this. @MarkVedder